# Quelle différence y a-t-il entre « Bonjour » et « bonne journée » ?

Tags: usage, sens

D’usage, on dit « bonjour » en rencontrant quelqu’un, et « bonne journée » en le quittant. Y a-t-il une différence de sens entre les deux ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je n'ai pas l'impression qu'il y a de différence de sens, mais effectivement l'usage est de dire *« Bonjour »* pour saluer à la rencontre et *« Bonne journée »* lorsque l'on prend congé.

Il me semble que *« Bonjour »* pouvait être utilisé pour prendre congé également. La traduction française du roman de J.R.R. Tolkien *Bilbo le hobbit* joue sur ce double sens lors de la rencontre entre Gandalf et Bilbo.

D'ailleurs *« Bien le bonjour ! »* peut être aussi bien utilisé en arrivant qu'en partant.

Answer (score 5):

> **Bonne journée** means **Have a nice day**
>
> **Bonjour** means **good morning** or ***Hello*** (for starting the conversation)

Answer (score 1):

*Bonjour* n'a plus trace pour moi de son sens étymologique. Par contre, quand je dis *bonne journée* en prenant congé de quelqu'un, l'intention y est; si je suis hostile, en colère ou même indifférent, je dirai *au revoir* (que je peux dire aussi aux personnes que j'apprécie sans être fâché avec elles, simplement le *bonne journée* n'est pas chez moi au moins une formule automatique).